# переключение кнопки next textfield

Tags: ios

Не могу разобраться с переключением кнопки next на клавиатуре в UITextField. У меня сегментированая таблица и мне нужно что б при нажатии на кнопку курсор переходил в следующий Textfield а в конце, при нажатии на кнопку Done клавиатура пряталась в сториборде я понимаю как ето сделать, а вот при использовании cell ничего не могу найти. Плюс я заметил проблему, что последний cell клавиатура прячет под собой.

Мне хотя б механизм роботы понять
Спасибо

Comment: про клавиатуру выносите в отдельной вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В протоколе `UITextFieldDelegate` есть метод `- textFieldShouldReturn:`, вам надо в нем держать всю бизнес логику, т.е. вы проверяете какой textField активен и если это последний, то `[textField resignFirstResponder];`, если не последний то передать firstResponder следующему `[nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];`.

Традиционно, чтобы это реализовать используются тэги. Каждому своему textField назначаете тэг, например от 1 до 5. и потом в проверке каждый текст филд передает респондера следующему по тэгу, Последний делает resign.